# Does ASP.NET Core JWT Authentication support multiple symmetric signing keys?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

Some libraries like https://www.nuget.org/packages/JWT support the concept of multiple symmetric signing keys.

- https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt/blob/6d922587515831f3bc17740db4cc42fa4d49de39/src/JWT/JwtValidator.cs#L123
- https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt/blob/6d922587515831f3bc17740db4cc42fa4d49de39/src/JWT/JwtDecoder.cs#L101

I would like to use the MS Provided `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` implementation if possible. Does that implementation support multiple symmetric signing keys?

The [SymmetricSecurityKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.symmetricsecuritykey?view=azure-dotnet) class appears to only support a single key.

Multiple calls to `JwtBearerExtensions.AddJwtBearer` throw an exception: `InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Bearer`

The reason for wanting to support multiple signing keys is to support a rolling keys scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Custom `IssuerSigningKeyResolver` in `TokenValidationParameters` could be used to provide multiple keys :

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (string token, SecurityToken securityToken, string kid, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) =>
        {

            List<SecurityKey> keys = new List<SecurityKey>();

            var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("yourFirstkey"));
            keys.Add(signingKey);
            var signingKey1 = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("yourSecondkey"));
            keys.Add(signingKey1);
            return keys;
        },
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `JwtBearerOptions` `TokenValidationParameters` property contains a `IssuerSigningKeys` property that allows you to provide multiple `SecurityKey`s

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.issuersigningkeys?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Tokens_TokenValidationParameters_IssuerSigningKeys

```
services
    .AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            IssuerSigningKeys = new[]
            {
                new RsaSecurityKey(signingKey01),
                new RsaSecurityKey(signingKey02),
            },
        };
    });
```